# How do you retrieve deleted Google bookmarks back so you can use them?

Tags: google-chrome, google-bookmarks

How do I get deleted Google bookmarks back?  I've looked in bookmark manager for them but I accidentally deleted the bookmarks ad I need them.

Answer (score 0):

Your only chance is to log in to your browser and sync your bookmarks which will revive all the bookmarks you had backed up. Of course only if you had synchronization of bookmarks allowed prior to your current state.

Comment: huh whats a browser, how do I sync my bookmarks?

Comment: @NicholasFord https://youtu.be/BrXPcaRlBqo